# Shapefile to ArcGIS JavaScript JSON format?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert SHP into GPX or JSON?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25936/how-to-convert-shp-into-gpx-or-json)

We're in the proces of adding a new feature to our Web Application where we employ the use of ESRI's ArcGIS Javascript API alongside other ESRI server products.

How would one go about converting an ESRI Shapefile format into ArcGIS Javascript API compatible JSON?

Near as I can tell, there are many examples of doing this very "thing" but converting to GeoJSON. AFAIK ArcGIS Javascript API does not understand or work with GeoJSON.